# How do I go to a different scene in upbge without the game restarting automatically?

Tags: game-engine

when I switch the scene while test the game the game restarts. How do I keep the game from restarting when I switch the scene?

Comment: On scene change, save all scene attributes as a variables. That way you can assign those variables, almost like a checkpoint after you've changed your scene.

Comment: sorry for the late reply. I don't know how to do this

Comment: Use GlobalDict.